# Passing C value to Lua

Tags: c, lua, binding

Right now I am working on strengthening my C skills by wrapping SDL to Lua. Right now I am working on passing Lua images. However, it appears it pass it right. I did a test, printing the value of the pre- passed SDL_Textue and the one that arrived, and they seemed the same. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks!

```
static int drawSprite(lua_State* alua) {

    textureDim.x = 100;
    textureDim.y = 100;
    textureDim.w = 100;
    textureDim.h = 100;

    SDL_Texture *param = (SDL_Texture*)lua_touserdata(alua,1);
    cout << param << endl;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, param, NULL, &textureDim);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, testimg, NULL, &textureDim);
    lua_pop(alua, 1);
    return 1;
}

static const luaL_Reg gSpriteFuncs[] = {
    // Creation
    { "new", loadSprite },
    { "draw", drawSprite },
    { NULL, NULL }
};


static int loadSprite(lua_State* alua) {
    // Allocate memory for a pointer to to object
    SDL_Texture **s = (SDL_Texture **)lua_newuserdata(alua, sizeof(SDL_Texture *));


    *s = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "cooldawg.png");
    cout << s << endl;
    lua_getglobal(alua, "Sprite"); // Use global table 'Sprite' as metatable
    lua_setmetatable(alua, -2);

    return 1;
}
// bah
```

Comment: First of all: use [luaL_newmetatable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_newmetatable) and [luaL_checkudata](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_checkudata). Then look at your userdata type on allocation and later use in **drawSprite**.

Comment: @Youka Hey, thanks for responding! I am kind of confused about your answer, mainly the **luaL_checkudata** part. Do you think you could describe that a bit more? Doesn't checkudata do the same thing as touserdata?            Thanks!

Comment: @Prynok: `luaL_checkudata` also makes sure that you have the right kind of userdata (there may be many different types). `luaL_newmetatable` and `luaL_checkudata` go together: one creates a metatable for a new kind of userdata (identified by a name), and `luaL_checkudata` checks for that specific kind (again specified by the name). Also `luaL_checkudata` raises an error if the argument is wrong, `lua_touserdata` just returns `NULL`.

Comment: `luaL_newmetatable` creates the metatable with given name in registry if not done so far and always pushes the table reference on the stack, so this function serves for both common use cases: make sure the metatable exists and give access to him. `luaL_checkudata` first checks the value at given stack position for being userdata **and** having the metatable with given name and then returns the userdata pointer. Both functions work well together for save use of userdata and the associated metatable.

Comment: in `drawSprite` remove `lua_pop` and instead `return 0`. Lua will pop the arguments off the stack and your `drawSprite` is not returning anything.